# Where can I get Tyvek maps?

Tags: maps, tyvek

I'd like to get some Tyvek maps, both topographical maps and regular street maps of a few U.S. cities.

Where can I get these?

Comment: Have you considered buying the soft-surface tyvek and printing yourself?

Comment: @Russell I don't know where I would get images of sufficient resolution for street maps, and I would like both types of maps in color which I cannot print.  If I can get the images I could potentially have them printed, but in my experience that will be a lot more expensive than if a general Tyvek map service exists.

Comment: @MrWizard -- A general service would likely be cheaper.  As to the printing, you can usually print at Fedex if you have the images.  For topo there are a couple of online sites that let you download good resolution images, but I'm not aware of anything for streets.

Comment: Bear in mind, most consumer-grade printing shops will print with pigment-based inks (water soluble). While it's possible to print on synthetics like Tyvek with these inks, they won't set perfectly and can smear or run. Solvent-based inks are a must if you want a good durable print on Tyvek.

Answer (score 3):

Palomar has a line of waterproof, soft, pliable maps called ["Crumpled City"](https://www.palomarweb.com/product/crumpled-city/). They have cities all over the world. Some in the United States include New York, New York; Chicago, Illinois; San Francisco, California; Boston, Massachusetts; Miami, Florida, and others.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the answers will be scattered.  I don't know of any one source of Tyvek maps that cover everything.

For the White Mountains of New Hampshire, the AMC publishes quite decent trail maps in Tyvek.  Unfortunately, the White Mountain Guide book comes standard with paper maps.  You have to buy the Tyvek maps separately.  They cost more, but I find them worth it.  They really do stand up to abuse and wetness very well.